# handleChange formik field

Tags: reactjs, formik

I'm trying to build an address component with formik, so the first input is an autocomplete, who set the values of the other field.
The problem is when I delete the content of autocomplete, values of formik set to null but formik field save the last value.

This is the field:

```
<Field
    component={TextField}
    fullWidth
    type="text"
    name={`${name}.value.codePostal`}
    placeholder="address postal"
/>
```

Comment: Can you please share the entire form?

Comment: it's just a formik form, my qst is it possible to add onChange to formik field , to re-render the field after the change of values

Comment: You can use a custom field, pass an onChange handler, then use formik.handleChange and formik.setFieldValue for your logic. I believe the form should rerender after calling formik.setFieldValue.